# Regular Expressions: Matching Song names in Python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm currently working on a project to parse data from a music database and I'm creating a search function using regular expressions in python (version 3.5.1).

I would like to create a regular expression to make the song names- songs without characters following the name and songs with feature details - but not songs containing given song's name in the matching song's name(examples may help illustrate my point):

What I'd like to match:

1. Work
2. Work (ft. Drake)

What would NOT like to match:

1. Work it
2. Workout

My current regular expression is ' **/Work(\s(\w+)?/** ' but this matches all 4 example cases.

Can someone help me figure out an expression to accomplish this?

Comment: Something like `Work\b(?: \(?ft\. \w+\)?)?$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd go with something like

```
^Work(?:\s+\(.+\))?$
```

which will match your two provided test cases, but not the two you want to avoid. If you want to make it a but more specific regarding matching who the artist is, you can go with something like

```
^Work(?:\s+\((?:ft.|featuring).+\))?$
```

Which will still match your two cases, but will only match stuff in the brackets that starts with "ft." or "featuring".

Comment: perfect. Thank you for your help! I'm just beginning my work with regular expressions :)

Comment: @CodingDancer: If an answer is helpful, or solves your problem, it's generally considered a good idea to mark it as the answer using the little checkmark icon to the left of it. That way, when others have a similar problem, they can see what helped you :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm new to stack overflow :)